# Handling panics in go routines

Tags: go, recovery, panic

I understand that to handle panic recover is used. But the following block fails to recover when panic arises in go routine

```
func main() {
    done := make(chan int64)
    defer fmt.Println("Graceful End of program")
    defer func() {
     r := recover()
     if _, ok := r.(error); ok {
        fmt.Println("Recovered")
     }
    }()

    go handle(done)
    for {
        select{
        case <- done:
        return
        }
    } 
}

func handle(done chan int64) {
    var a *int64
    a = nil

    fmt.Println(*a)
    done <- *a
}
```

However following block is able to execute as expected

```
func main() {
    done := make(chan int64)
    defer fmt.Println("Graceful End of program")
    defer func() {
     r := recover()
     if _, ok := r.(error); ok {
        fmt.Println("Recovered")
     }
    }()

    handle(done)
    for {
        select{
        case <- done:
        return
        }
    } 
}

func handle(done chan int64) {
    var a *int64
    a = nil

    fmt.Println(*a)
    done <- *a
}
```

How to recover from panics that arise in go routines. Here is the link for playground : https://play.golang.org/p/lkvKUxMHjhi

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Recover only works when called from the same goroutine as the panic is called in. From the Go blog:

> The process continues up the stack until all functions in the current
>   goroutine have returned, at which point the program crashes

You would have to have a deferred recover within the goroutine.

https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

The docs / spec also includes the same :

> While executing a function F, an explicit call to panic or a run-time
>   panic terminates the execution of F. Any functions deferred by F are
>   then executed as usual. Next, any deferred functions run by F's caller
>   are run, and so on up to any deferred by the top-level function in the
>   **executing goroutine**. At that point, the program is terminated and the
>   error condition is reported, including the value of the argument to
>   panic. This termination sequence is called panicking

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics

Answer (score 1):

I use the following way to handle this case, and it works as expected.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("Graceful End of program")
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Recovered:", r)
        }
    }()

    done := make(chan int64)
    var panicVar interface{}

    go handle(done, &panicVar)

WAIT:
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            break WAIT // break WAIT: goroutine exit normally
        default:
            if panicVar != nil {
                break WAIT // break WAIT: goroutine exit panicked
            }

            // wait for goroutine exit
        }

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Microsecond)
    }

    if panicVar != nil {
        panic(panicVar) // panic again
    }
}

func handle(done chan int64, panicVar *interface{}) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            // pass panic variable outside
            *panicVar = r
        }
    }()

    var a *int64
    a = nil

    fmt.Println(*a)
    done <- *a
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/t0wXwB02pa3

Comment: instead of using var to store panic state, use channels. This way you can remove the sleep & for in main. select alone can serve in this case.