# Panics in libraries that spawn goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

What if an imported library spawns a goroutine that can panic? In this case, there is nothing a developer can do to stop the program from exiting.

Like in this code, calling a bad library with deferred recover does not help as the library is spawning a goroutine that panics, and it cannot be caught by the main's recover.

Do I understand it correct that the only remedy is to be very careful when choosing dependencies for one's project and hope that the authors do not do something similar?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        r := recover()
        if r != nil {
            fmt.Println("panic caught")
        }
    }()

    badLibrary()
}

func badLibrary() {
    go recklessFunction()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func recklessFunction() {
    panic("something went wrong")
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's why the general recommendation is to leave concurrency to the user of your library.

Comment: One way is to have your main go routine recover from any panic that may be raised by APIs you have no control over.

Comment: @MargachChris The `main()` function cannot recover from panics happening on other goroutines.

Comment: @icza Thank you for pointing this out but by "main", I meant the function on top on the call stack that would recover from the panic and not to allow the panic to propagate the ```main()``` function.

Comment: @MargachChris Yes, but the question is about this happening in a 3rd party lib, where the asker has "no authority".

Comment: See also: [Handling panics in go routines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409011/handling-panics-in-go-routines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, you can't do anything about that. Neither can you if a dependency calls `os.Exit()` for example.

Launching goroutines as a library is often bad practice anyway, let the client (user of the library) choose if concurrent execution (a goroutine) is wanted, adding the `go` keyword is trivial. There are exceptions of course.